# Find location of files in an archive with unknown padding separation

Tags: perl

I have a number of large binary archive files, each of which holds a collection of other files. I know where a file is, its starting position (a fixed offset) and its length (which varies but I am able to find it) so I am able to extract it.

Once that file finishes there is a sequence of `NUL` characters before the next file with a length that depends on the size of the preceding file data.

I have my own solution for now, which is to find the length of the filler between the files by searching for the first non-`NUL` character.

```
my @KNOWNFILE_FillerSize;

# Continue from the extraction/read of the previous known file
# (to get the unknown offset of the EOF)
my $KNOWNFILE_EOF_CurrentLocation = tell $bin;

# Read a large amount, just in case the space is insanely large
read($bin, my $KNOWNFILE_FillerSize, 0x183E1); 

while ( $KNOWNFILE_FillerSize =~ m/($Null_Filler_Search)/g ) { # [^\x00]

    my $KNOWNFILE_FillerSize        = $1;
    my $KNOWNFILE_FillerSize_Offset = $-[0] + $KNOWNFILE_EOF_CurrentLocation;

    push @KNOWNFILE_FillerSize, "$KNOWNFILE_FillerSize_Offset";
}

my $KNOWNFILE_FillerSize_FirstOffset = $KNOWNFILE_FillerSize[0];
my $KNOWNFILE_FillerSize_Result      = $KNOWNFILE_FillerSize_FirstOffset - $KNOWNFILE_EOF_CurrentLocation;
```

While this works, I have to re-read the known file, seeking to its offset and reading its data so that I can get back to the end of the file. From there I use the now-known filler size and add that to the end of file offset so I can get the start of the next file. Is there a better way?

Update: Now I have a new similar issue where I need to calculate the reverse of this. I have data, I need now to know its dynamic end point (So I ultimately don't know the size of the file, but I know it ends in a filler of FF). I have tried various regular expressions to match all non FF or to match only data that ISNT FF. Nothing seems to work... I'm tempted to raise another question on this.

Comment: Just how big can that "filler" be? Why not read the filler in small pops until you reach non-filler and then back up (seek) by the last read?

Comment: D0 to about 1ED0? But because I simply cannot know the length of filler, I just make it large enough that it would 100% skip the next file, ensuring it will be found.

Comment: If this noticeably affects efficiency (does it really?) you can implement a simplified version of one of search algorithms.  On the other hand, there are established binary formats for storing independent  files, with which you wouldn't have this problem; can you switch to one of them?

Comment: I just feel that the method I have used is just superfluous, I am sure I am missing some quick and easy solution to my problem. I cannot change binary formats as this is proprietary, for which is not designed to be extracted by the end user.

Comment: But how would you know what's in a byte without looking? If the possible length of zero section varies a lot perhaps search by bisecting (look in the middle, then in the middle of the upper or lower half, etc); it can't take many lookups.

Comment: How come you know the position of one file, but not the other? It seems your file format should have a table with the positions of every file. You say the way you have now works, but it means you can't have a file that starts with `00`.

Comment: Where does the crazy block size `0x183E1` come from? `read` reads from the system in 8 KiB chunks, so you should read in chunks of `0x2000` or a multiple of that.

Comment: @ikegami the file I am using does not have a list of positions for every file, but the header of the files (once found) does have the file size. The file that I don't know the address of starts with '01' and always will, thankfully. So I just find the first '01' among the filler of '00'. The block size is indeed crazy but thats not important, any size larger than the filler would have done the job,  also I am reading in binmode if that helps.

Comment: Re "*the file I am using does not have a list of positions for every file*", But it should.

Comment: Re "*any size larger than the filler would have done the job*", If that's true, then your code is quite fragile. You shouldn't rely on the block size being larger than the filler.

Comment: @ikegami The file simply does not list any positions (I have looked in both in big and little endian throughout the file based on known locations). This file is not designed to be examined by the end user, nor extracted. So I am ultimately working on the basis of what other people have discovered and what I can discover about the file through comparative analysis with other files (which are partly unique).

Comment: Re "*This file is not designed to be examined by the end user, nor extracted.*", That's obviously not true. There's no point in writing it if noone's going to read it.

Comment: @ikegami well its extracted flash memory from a pcb, by further extracting its contents it I and other technicians are able to modify it, repair corruption and learn about the system itself. So yeah its not designed to be examined.

Comment: That's obviously not true. There's no point in writing it if noone's going to read it.

Comment: @ikegami - shrug, I can't see how it functions beyond what I have currently.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to re-read the known file, seeking to its offset and reading its data

No, of course you don't. You say you know the length of the file, so `seek` to `$file_start + $file_length`

If your filler may be up to 0x1ED0 bytes, then just read 0x2000 bytes and find the first 0x01 character. There's no need to read the whole of the following file as well.

Fix your variable names. With everything beginning `KNOWNFILE` they all look the same because the eye is drawn to the capitals. (Plus, you can't really have a variable containing data on an *unknown* file. `my $filler_size` is *much* more readable, without any capitals at all, and is the regular format for Perl identifiers. Capitals are generally reserved for globals and package names.

Comment: oh sorry about the 'KNOWNFILE' thing, i renamed it so it would make more sense to you guys. its original variable name would have been confusing.

Comment: Ah I see. No worries, but "snake case"—lower-case letters, digits and underscores—are preferred for Perl.